# it will not send me to the next page

Tags: php

hey this is so that I should just have put some infomation into the database but it is such that when it did it would not send me to export the login page. it will just be empty words white.

File name **activate.php**

```
<?php
            include ("include/database/db.php");
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `code`,`rank` FROM `brugere` WHERE `code` = ?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $g_code);
                $g_code = $_GET["code"];
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($code, $rank);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $count_res = $stmt->num_rows;
                $stmt->close();

                if($count_res > 0)
                {
                    if($rank == 0)
                    {
                        echo "<h3 class=\"toptitlecontent\">Godkende email</h3>";
                        echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Husk at skrive alt ude på siden!</li></ul></div>";
                        $_SESSION["code"] = $g_code;
                    ?>

                    <div id="midtbox_alt">
                        <form action="http://,,,.dk/activate_updater.php" method="post" name="formular" onsubmit="return validerform ()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <table border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Kategori</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td>
                                        <select name="kategori">
                                        <?php
                                        $query = "SELECT id_katogori, navn FROM kategori";
                                        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                                        while(list($id_katogori, $navn) = $result->fetch_row())
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value=\"$id_katogori\">$navn</option>";  
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Djnavn</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="djnavn"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Facebook</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="facebook"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Pris</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="pris"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Booking Email</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="email" name="booking"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Mobil</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="mobil"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Upload Profil</p></td>
                                        <td>:</td>
                                        <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            <textarea name="profiltekst" style="width:500px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
                            <input type="submit" value="Godkend brugere" name="godkendt-brugere">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    if($rank == 2)
                    {
                        echo "<h3 class=\"toptitlecontent\">Forkert Email</h3>";
                        echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Din bruger er allerede godkendt</li></ul></div>";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    /* Der er opstået en fejl */
                    echo "<h3 class=\"toptitlecontent\">Ukendt side!</h3>";
                    echo "<div id=\"box\"><ul><li>Der opstod en fejl</li></ul></div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

reason I have needless churning Here's how it is such a website does not get on google .. or here as I have spurget help and do not appear on google so others can see me or what to say?

HER **http://,,,.dk/activate_updater.php**

File name

activate_updater.php

```
<?php include ("include/database/db.php");?>
<?php
session_start();
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `brugere` SET `rank`=2, `katogori`=?, `djnavn`=?, `profilbillede`=?, `profiltekst`=?, `facebook`=?, `pris`=?, `booking`=?, `mobil`=? WHERE `code`=?'))
    {

        $stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiis', $katogori, $djnavn, $profilbillede, $profiltekst, $facebook, $pris, $booking, $mobil, $g_code);
        //fra input ting ting..
        $katogori = $_POST["kategori"];
        $djnavn = $_POST["djnavn"];
        $profilbillede = $file;
        $profiltekst = $_POST["profiltekst"];
        $facebook = $_POST["facebook"];
        $pris = $_POST["pris"];
        $booking = $_POST["booking"];
        $mobil = $_POST["mobil"];
        $g_code = $_SESSION["code"];

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

**so problem is just it will not let me be redirected to another page ..**

Comment: white page of doom, usually means you don't have errors being displayed, so turn them on or see the error logs.

Comment: how do I do it and what should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are redirecting at all, but this is not going to work:

```
<?php include ("include/database/db.php");?>
<?php
session_start();
```

You are sending output to the browser (a new line between the closing and the opening of the php tags) and `session_start` needs to send headers, which it cannot do if the headers have already been sent.

I'm guessing you'll see at least one `headers already sent` error message, when you enable error messaging at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

**Edit:** To be clear, I don't see any redirect in `activate_updater.php` nor does it display anything upon a successful update, so if the `headers already sent` part is not the problem, it's probably this.

Comment: I feel like most of the apache/php-Setups I worked with - whether in a pro environment or out-of-the-box - ignored a newline after a closing ?>. Other experiences?

Comment: @Lukx I do, although not recently as I avoid sending anything until the very end.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php `The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.`

Comment: @Lukx Anyway, if that's not the problem, then the problem probably is that `activate_updater.php` does not redirect nor does it display anything upon a successful update like I mentioned in the first line...

Comment: <?php include ("include/database/db.php");
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
session_start();

Comment: @Jesper Petersen I would place it at the top, before anything else, including the db include.

Comment: it works now after I got it right on to it!

here; <? php include ("include / database / db.php");
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Comment: @Jesper Petersen Good to hear you solved it.

Comment: I'll make a new tård because I also need to have upload an image to user profile. :) But I have problem but I just do :) thanks for your help again! ...